# Outlook Automation from VB.net (Visual Studio 201)

Tags: vb.net, outlook

We have some very old VB6 applications that used automation to create Excel Spreadsheets, Word Documents and Outlook Calendar events.  Now we want to upgrade those applications to VB.net and perform the same automation tasks.  Our issue is that there appears to be very sparse documentation on how to do this now.  There is plenty on creating Add-Ons, or interacting with COM objects, but neither of these suit our purposes.  We need to be able to interact with Office 2016 (which is presumably .Net not COM) directly to create our outputs.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The VB6 code must be using COM (or COM Interop at least)

Comment: I think your question is too broad to be answered. Implementing all those in VB.net is rather easy (I'd expect it was much more difficult in VB6) and there are plenty of examples for particular tasks. The parts of your code where you compile your documents can possibly stay as they are, while I would scrap completely the parts which interacts with Office and replace them with new VB.net code.

Comment: Check out VSTO  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Office

Answer (score 0):

The Office object model is the same for all kind of applications - COM add-ins or automation applications. Anyway, you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How to automate Word from Visual Basic .NET to create a new document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383)
- [How to automate Excel from Visual Basic .NET to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302094)
- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301982)
- [How to automate Outlook by using Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/220595)