# how to read outlook email in a directory files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, email, directory

I am new in vb.net development and I must read informations (subject, body, ...) in Outlook email files that are in a disk directory (D:\mails\to-read\message1.msg, D:\mails\to-read\message2.msg, ...).

Is it possible ?

Can you please explain me ? With example ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://googlethatforyou.com?q=vb.net%20read%20msg%20file%20sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Outlook object model (Outlook automation) is a possible option you can use the [NameSpace.OpenSharedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.openshareditem) method which opens a shared item from a specified path or URL. This method is used to open iCalendar appointment (.ics) files, vCard (.vcf) files, and Outlook message (.msg) files. So, in the code you will get a `MailItem` object where you could get all the required properties.

```
Public Sub TestOpenSharedItem()
    Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oSharedItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.Folder   

    ' Get a reference to a NameSpace object.
    Set oNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")'Open the Signed Message (.msg) file containing the shared item.
     Set oSharedItem = oNamespace.OpenSharedItem("C:\Temp\RegularMessage.msg")

    MsgBox oSharedItem.Subject

    oSharedItem.Close (olDiscard)
    Set oSharedItem = Nothing

    Set oSharedItem = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oNamespace = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Eugene, 

Thanks you for your quick answer but I am new in vb.net and I have an error when I compile the vb.net code with vbc.exe : 

error BC30002: Type 'Outlook.NameSpace' non défini.

        Dim oNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace.

Can you please help me ?

Comment: This is a VBA code, to get it running under the VB.NET environment you must instantiate a new Outlook instance (see the `Application` object in the code). See [Outlook Automation from VB.net (Visual Studio 201)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769192/outlook-automation-from-vb-net-visual-studio-201).

Comment: Eugene, it works : I have add the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll in reference of the vbc.exe compiler, imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook in the vb.net code and instantiate a new Outlook instance. Thanks a lot for your help.